# SignalR -- Error in getting to /signalR/hubs

Tags: signalr

I am trying to run the sample signalR code. When i run it inbuild Webserver it works fine. But when i host the code in the virtualDirectory getting the following error

**Line 35:
Object is null**

It comes down to the point where it looks like it couldnt locate the AUTOGenerated signalR/Hubs file ....

I have the following code

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" ></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have used fiddler which shows me it is looking for the file in the following direction

GET `http://myserver/SignalRChat/signalr/hubs` 404 Not Found (text/html) GET `http://myserver/SignalRChat/signalr/hubs` 404 Not Found (text/html)

I have change the following line to all of this but none of them seems to work

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/signalr/hubs">`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs">`

or

`<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl(" hubs="" signalr="">// // ]]></script>`

Nothing is working ... Could anyone suggest me on this

Comment: You could statically add the hubs file to your script folder and reference it directly, if you are not able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The virtual directory doesn't seem to be mapped correctly to the physical directory. The /signalr/hubs url isn't pointing to the correct location in the physical directory. You might need to modify the path in the Routes.MapHubs() to ensure that it maps to correct location in the physical directory.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the similar issue, its the problem with the virtual directory.

Try replacing

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs">
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/SignalRChat/signalr/hubs">
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

From http://sylvester-lee.blogspot.com.au/2014/03/aspnet-signalr.html
My solution was 
Startup.cs

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        ConfigureAuth(app);

        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
        hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        hubConfiguration.EnableJavaScriptProxies = true;

        app.MapSignalR("/signalr", hubConfiguration);
    }
```

In aspx file: <script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>

Answer (score 0):

My app was mostly client-side html and js and after trying to run it on a new Windows 10 PC I was getting similar error - **until I realized I had not enabled ASP.NET in IIS** (run "Programs and Features" -> Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> ASP.NET 4.7 in my case)